# ViewModel reference in a CompoundView (Custom View)

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I am following `MVVM` architecture using `Android Architecture Components` and the `Data Binding` library.

**TL;DR**

Does having a reference to a `ViewModel` object in a compound view violate MVVM architecture? I looked over examples by Google and have only seen it used in Activity/Fragment XML but not in custom views.

**Code in question**

I have a compound view that I would like to re-use in a number of places. It gets instantiated from XML. This view gets populated from user input. I would like to make sure whatever user enters survives an orientation change. Please consider the following code I made up in a hurry to illustrate the scenario:

```
public class RestaurantActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RestaurantViewModel viewModel;

    RestaurantActivityBinding binding;

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.restaurant_activity );

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of( this ).get( RestaurantViewModel.class );

        //is this "legal" for MVVM
        binding.selectionView.setRestaurantViewModel( viewModel );

        viewModel.extraHotSause.observe ( this, new Observer() {

          @Override
          void onChange(Boolean extraHotSauce ) {
               binding.selectionView.extraHotSauce( extraHotSauce );
          }

        });
    }
}
```

View Model:

```
public class RestaurantViewModel extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel {
    public MutableLiveData<Boolean> extraHotSauce = new MutableLiveData<>();
}
```

Restaurant Selection View:

```
public class RestaurantSelectionView extends ConstraintLayout {

    private RestaurantSelectionViewBinding binding;

    private RestaurantViewModel viewModel;
    ...

    private void init() {            
        binding = RestaurantSelectionViewBinding.inflate(...);
    }

    public void onExtraHotSauceSelection( boolean yesPlease ) {
          viewModel.extraHotSauce.setValue( yesPlease );
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
          viewModel = null;
          super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }
}
```

Comment: Views already have a mechanism for saving and restoring their internal state across orientation changes with [onSaveInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSaveInstanceState()) and [onRestoreInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Parcelable)), respectively.

Comment: @ianhanniballake same mechanisms could be used in Activities and Fragments too, but seems like using a `ViewModel` is now a preferred method because of separation of concerns, its reactive nature, etc. Is a `ViewModel` only meant to be used in Activities/Fragments then?

Comment: Saving instance state and ViewModels are very different things and are not interchangeable as per [this blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/viewmodels-persistence-onsaveinstancestate-restoring-ui-state-and-loaders-fc7cc4a6c090). Having completely separate controllers (or activities/fragments that take that role) from the Views and having those controllers have ViewModels is one valid way of architecturing your app and avoiding having Views do too much

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thanks for the link to the blog post. It was a good read. As for Activity/Fragments with ViewModels and their interaction with Compound Views, sounds like what you're saying is that a VM reference should stay in A/F and a CV would rather interact with it's A/F through perhaps an interface to access a VM. Am I getting the gist? Again, thanks for your time.

Comment: Your code doesn't need a ViewModel at all, but yes, what you describe is the general pattern I was suggesting.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thanks. What if I use a `DataBinding` library instead and keep a reference to the bound object in the VM - would keeping that bound object in a VM fit the MVVM architecture?